# Under what conditions do we have $\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx \leq C \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 |f^{\prime}(x)|^2 dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have been trying to prove the inequality

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx \leq C \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 |f^{\prime}(x)|^2 dx$$

for some constant $C$, under the most general set of assumptions possible. Obviously we need to have that $f$ is square-integrable and differentiable.

I can prove a version of the inequality with $C=4$, provided that additionally $x |f(x)|^2 \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ (the proof is by integration by parts and the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality). Can this be improved? Thank you.

Comment: Why the absolute values?

Comment: @martycohen No reason, they just look better than a second set of parentheses.

Comment: The constant $4$ is sharp. I have added a section to my answer showing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Constant is $\boldsymbol{\le4}$**

Whatever conditions are needed to justify the following steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\left|\int_x^\infty f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&\le\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty t^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\int_x^\infty t^{3/2}|f'(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\int_0^\infty2x^{-1/2}\int_x^\infty t^{3/2}|f'(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{3/2}|f'(t)|^2\int_0^t2x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\tag4\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{3/2}|f'(t)|^24t^{1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5\\
&=4\int_0^\infty t^2|f'(t)|^2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: Funamental Theorem of Calculus (assuming $f$ vanishes at $\infty$)
$(2)$: Cauchy Schwarz
$(3)$: integrate
$(4)$: change order of integration
$(5)$: integrate
$(6)$: simplify

It seems that if $(6)$ exists and $f$ vanishes at $\infty$, the inequality holds.

---

**$\boldsymbol{4}$ is Sharp**

Define
$$
f_a(t)=\frac{t^{-1/2}}{t^{-a}+t^a}\tag7
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f_a(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-1}}{\left(t^{-a}+t^a\right)^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag8\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{2a-1}}{\left(1+t^{2a}\right)^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag9\\
&=\frac1{2a}\int_0^\infty\frac1{(1+t)^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{10}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{2a}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(8)$: apply $(7)$
$\phantom{1}(9)$: multiply numerator and denominator by $t^{2a}$
$(10)$: substitute $t^{2a}\mapsto t$
$(11)$: evaluate

Taking the derivative of $(7)$
$$
f_a'(t)=\frac{t^{-\frac32+a}\left(4a+(1-2a)\left(1+t^{2a}\right)\right)}{2\left(1+t^{2a}\right)^2}\tag{12}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^2f_a'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^\infty t^2\,\left(\frac{t^{-\frac32+a}\left(4a+(1-2a)\left(1+t^{2a}\right)\right)}{2\left(1+t^{2a}\right)^2}\right)^2\mathrm{d}t\tag{13}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-1+2a}\left(4a+(1-2a)\left(1+t^{2a}\right)\right)^2}{4\left(1+t^{2a}\right)^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{14}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{16a^2+8a(1-2a)(1+t)+(1-2a)^2(1+t)^2}{8a(1+t)^4}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{15}\\[3pt]
&=\frac23a+\frac12(1-2a)+\frac1{8a}(1-2a)^2\tag{16}\\[6pt]
&=\frac16a+\frac1{8a}\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(13)$: apply $(12)$
$(14)$: simplify
$(15)$: substitute $t^{2a}\mapsto t$
$(16)$: integrate
$(17)$: simplify

The ratio of $(11)$ over $(17)$ is $\frac4{1+\frac43a^2}$. As $a\to0$, this gets arbitrarily close to $4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It seems that one can completely avoid the condition $x f^2(x) \to 0$.

Comment: @JohnK Well, no. If you simply delete that condition tthe first step $f(x)=-\int_x^\infty f'(t)$ is wrong. (You can make this proof work without that condition, for example by saying $f(x)=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_x^{x_n}f'(t)\,dt$ as I suggested, but without that condition the proof above is not quite right.)

Comment: Hmm. (1) is right by FTC, _because_ $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ (which follows from $xf(x)^2\to0$.) That's assuming that $\int_x^\infty$ is taken as a limit, not a Lebesgue integral...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Don't we have $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ by square integrability?

Comment: @JohnK: I added that $f$ must vanish at $\infty$ since I had only required $(6)$ to exist, which would allow $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, once again. Very enlightening answer.

Comment: @JohnK No, $f\in L^2$ certainly does not imply $f(x)\to0$. For example let $I_n=[n,n+1/n^2$  and set $f=\sum_1^\infty\chi_{I_n}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @JohnK Hmm, by square integrability of _what_, exactly? If you assume $f$ and $f'$ are both square integrable then  it does follow that $f(x)\to0$ (becasue $f$ is uniformly continuous...)

Comment: @JohnK: Note also that $(1)$ assumes that $f$ vanishes at $\infty$.

Comment: "Note also that (1) assumes that $f$ vanishes at $\infty$." It's not clear who you meant to address this to. If to me: My point was exactly that (1) does  not explciitly assume this, although it requires it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I had meant it as a general comment, not directed at anyone in particular, but I have directed it at JohnK and I amended the explanation.

Comment: In any case, (i) if you assume at the start that $\int t^2|f(t)|^2<\infty$ then it _follows_ that $f(x)\to0$, although including that would lengthen the proof, (ii) the result holds without any extra assumptions, more or less as above, using tthe fact that $f(x_n)\to0$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: $(i)$ is not true. A counterexample follows much the same lines as yours above. $I_k=\left[k,k+\frac1{k^4}\right]$. Consider $f(t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty[t\in I_k]$

Comment: There was a typo in (i); I meant that if you assume at the start (as you do at the end) that $\int_0^\infty t^2|f'(t)|^2<\infty$ then $f(x)\to0$. Proof: $\int_1^\infty |f'(t)|^2<\infty$, hence $|f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|^{1/2}$ for $x,y\ge1$; certainly uniform continuity plus square integrability implies qed. (And of course you can make that assumption wlog, since if $\int t^2|f'(t)|^2=\infty$ there's nothing to prove.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful addendum, it completely solves the problem.

Comment: @JohnK: The only inequality on the way to $(6)$ is Cauchy-Schwarz, and equality in Cauchy-Schwarz only happens when the two functions are parallel (constant multiple of each other). That means that $f'(t)^2=t^{-3}$, which says that $f(t)$ is a constant multiple of $t^{-1/2}$. Unfortunately, if $f(t)$ is a constant multiple of $t^{-1/2}$, neither $f(t)^2$ nor $t^2f'(t)^2$ are integrable, so there is no function that gives a constant of $4$. This is why I use $\frac{t^{-1/2}}{t^{-a}+t^a}$ and send $a\to0$.

Comment: +1, an ingenious solution! I am very curious about how you came up with the term $t^{\pm\frac32}$ in Equations (2). Did you put an indeterminate $t^u$ into the Cauchy-Schwartz to see which $u$ gives the desired inequality? Could you please explain your intuition?

Comment: @Hans: I thought I explained my thoughts in the comment before yours.

Comment: That comment explains the origin of Equation $(7)$ which is a feat in itself. I figured out the rationale for it roughly matching yours. My question concerns with Equation $(2)$ particularly the splitting $f'(t)=t^{-\frac34}t^{-\frac34}f'(t)$. My guess is that you put $f'(t)=t^{-u}t^uf'(t)$ for some indeterminate $u$ and put it into the Cauchy-Schwartz then solve for $u$ that gives you the desired inequality with a constant factor. Is this your approach?

Comment: @Hans: ah, sorry. Yes, I tried $t^{-\alpha}$ and $t^\alpha f'(t)^2$ and got a constant of $\frac1{(2-\alpha)(\alpha-1)}$ and then $\alpha=\frac32$ is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some thoughts about this question. My guess is that $C=4$ is the optimal value. The computations below are not totally rigorous and some arguments are missing. This can only give some directions for the question.

Consider the function $f$ defined on $[0, +\infty)$ as follows, with $a>1/2$ and $\varepsilon \in [0,1/10]$:
$$
f(x)=x^a\quad \mbox{ if } x\leq 1-\varepsilon \quad \mbox{and}\quad f(x)=x^{-a}\quad\mbox{ if } x\geq 1+\varepsilon.
$$
On $[1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon]$ construct $f$ such as it is globally of class $\mathcal{C}^1$.

$f$ verifies the conditions and we have
$$
f'(x)=ax^{a-1}\quad \mbox{ if } x\leq 1-\varepsilon \quad \mbox{and}\quad f(x)=-ax^{-a-1}\quad\mbox{ if } x\geq 1+\varepsilon.
$$
Assuming $f'$ is bounded on $[1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon]$ we can compute both integrals and we get, taking $\varepsilon \to 0$:
$$J\doteq \int_0^{\infty} f(x)^2\mbox{d}x\approx\int_0^1x^{2a}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^{\infty}x^{-2a}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{4a}{4a^2-1}.$$
And similarly
$$K\doteq \int_0^{\infty} x^2f'(x)^2\mbox{d}x\approx\int_0^1 a^2 x^{2a}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^{\infty} a^2 x^{-2a}\mathrm{d}x=a^2\dfrac{4a}{4a^2-1}=a^2 J.$$
Finally $$J\approx K/a^2.$$
Taking $a$ close from $1/2$ we obtain $J \approx 4 K$, indicating that $4$ should be the optimal constant.

Note nevertheless that when $a \to 1/2$, we have $J \sim \dfrac{1}{2a-1}$ which diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the nice example.

Answer (score 2):

You say you can prove it *if* $x|f(x)|^2\to0$. It seems very likely that your proof can be modified to work without that extra assumption.

Because there must exist $x_n\to\infty$ such that $x_n|f(x_n)|^2\to0$; if not then $|f(x)|^2\ge c/x$ for all $x\ge A$, which implies that $\int|f(x)|^2=\infty$.

I haven't seen your proof, but "surely" it works just using integration by parts on the interval $(0,x_n)$ instead of an arbitrary interval.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the second condition is superfluous since I have restricted attention to $[0, \infty]$.